# How can i uninstall Google Chrome using Power Shell

Tags: google-chrome, powershell

I am working towards writing a powershell script for uninstalling the current version 54.0.2840.99 m of Google Chrome from my machine but could not be able to do so. I am using the following piece of code in my script:

```
$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {
$_.Name -match “Google Chrome”}
$app.Uninstall()
```

The chrome is installed in my machine but the above code is not showing Google Chrome in the list. It is returning null value and it could not be able to uninstall.

Could you please tell me where i have been went wrong or any other alternative solution for uninstalling the Google Chrome via PowerShell?

Comment: try: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\[yourversion]\Installer\setup.exe --uninstall --multi-install --chrome --system-level` ,also see the source link for more info http://www.itninja.com/question/how-to-uninstall-any-version-google-chrome-there-is-no-uninstall-string-how-to-identify-the-version-and-uninstall-by-path-appdata-google-version-uninstall

Comment: What command needs to be used in order to execute the statement provided you? Can we directly use as it is in my power shell script to uninstall ? Please suggest

Comment: If you run just `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product` is Chrome listed?

Comment: No James... Chrome is not being listed when i run that command... So i thought of uninstalling the chrome by getting the Uninstall string from the registry values but this didn't worked either... Is there any other way of uninstalling the existing Google Chrome via powershell

Comment: @Avshalom 's comment is the way you'll need to go then.

Comment: I would probably modify the command a bit to make sure it works on systems with non-standard program file folders and avoid any ambiguity.

`& %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\[yourversion]\Installer\setu‌​p.exe --uninstall --multi-install --chrome --system-level`

Comment: `Win32_Product` only contains software installed via Windows Installer (MSI).

Comment: Mike... How can the line be executed via power shell? Do we need to use any command in order to execute the line or we can provide it directly? Please suggest.

Comment: The following command worked but an UI has been displayed.where i need to click manually. My code should do the uninstall action in background process. Here i have passed the /silent argument but it didnt worked. Is this the correct argument. Without UI interaction uninstallation should be done in background process. Please suggest where i have wen wrong?                                                                 Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\47.0.2526.80\Installer\setup.exe' -ArgumentList '/uninstall', '/silent' -Wait

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome doesn't use WMI when installing chrome. You can use the command below to find the version, and uninstall chrome using its setup package.

```
(Get-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome').version | ForEach-Object {& ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Google\Chrome\Application\$_\Installer\setup.exe --uninstall --multi-install --chrome --system-level --force-uninstall}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
$GoogleChrome = [CimInstance](Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Google Chrome'})
If ($GoogleChrome -ne $null) {
    Write-Host 'Uninstalling Google Chrome'$GoogleChrome.Version
    Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $GoogleChrome -MethodName 'Uninstall' | Out-Null
}
```

The search for the uninstaller takes longer than I would like, but it works for the 64-bit version of Google Chrome we use.

Answer (score 0):

There might have been some changes with Chrome that gave me some trouble with the solutions above.  This worked for me just recently, and it will work with some other software packages too.  It also gives a good basis for confirming the package is no longer installed:

```
$target_computers='computer1','computer2','computer3'
$software_to_remove='chrome'

Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
$target_sessions=New-PSSession -ComputerName $target_computers


if ($software_to_remove -Like 'chrome') {
    Invoke-Command -Session (Get-PSSession) -ScriptBlock{
        $computer_name=$env:COMPUTERNAME
        $chrome_installed_object=(Get-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome')
        if ($chrome_installed_object -ne $null) {
            $chrome_version=($chrome_installed_object | select-object -ExpandProperty Version)
            $chrome_uninstaller_string=($chrome_installed_object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UninstallString)
            $chrome_uninstaller_full_string=($chrome_uninstaller_string+" --force-uninstall")
            Write-Host "For $computer_name, we have found the following version of Chrome: $chrome_version"
            Write-Host "Removing version $chrome_version"
            Write-Host "This is the Chrome uninstall string we are using: $chrome_uninstaller_full_string"
            cmd.exe /c $chrome_uninstaller_full_string 
            }
        }
    }


Invoke-Command -Session (Get-PSSession) -ScriptBlock{
param($software_to_remove)
$computer_name=$env:Computername
#Look at installed programs
Write-Host ("Looking for a package matching this pattern: "+$software_to_remove+" on server "+$computer_name)
$program_to_remove = $(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object -Property Name -Like "*$software_to_remove*")
if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($program_to_remove)) {
    Write-Host "These programs have been located: $program_to_remove"
    $oktoremove=$(Read-Host "OK to remove these programs (y or n)?")
    If (!($oktoremove -eq 'y')) {
        Write-Host 'Exiting the entire script on server $computer_name since you do not wish to take any further action now'
        exit
        }
    $program_to_remove.Uninstall()        
    }


#Look at installed packages
$PackageToRemove=$(Get-Package -Provider Programs -IncludeWindowsInstaller | Where-Object -Property Name -Like "*$software_to_remove*")
$PackageToRemove_name=$(Get-Package -Provider Programs -IncludeWindowsInstaller | Where-Object -Property Name -Like "*$software_to_remove*" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($PackageToRemove)) {    
    Write-Host "$PackageToRemove_name"
    $oktoremove=$(Read-Host "OK to remove software (y or n)?")
    If (!($oktoremove -eq 'y')) {
        Write-Host 'Exiting the entire script on server $computer_name since you do not wish to take any further action now'
        exit
        }
    Uninstall-Package -Name $PackageToRemove -Verbose -Force
    }



#Just in case the previous approach did not remove the package successfully, use the GUID this time
Get-Package -Provider Programs -IncludeWindowsInstaller | Where-Object -Property Name -Like "*$software_to_remove*" | Uninstall-Package



#Check again, just to make sure

$x86Path = "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
$installedItemsX86 = Get-ItemProperty -Path $x86Path | Select-Object -Property PSChildName, DisplayName, DisplayVersion

$x64Path = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
$installedItemsX64 = Get-ItemProperty -Path $x64Path | Select-Object -Property PSChildName, DisplayName, DisplayVersion

$installedItems = $installedItemsX86 + $installedItemsX64
$installedItems | Where-Object -FilterScript { $null -ne $_.DisplayName } | Sort-Object -Property DisplayName | ft

} -ArgumentList($software_to_remove)
```